# Does Django per-view cache add HTTP headers?

Tags: django, caching, cache-control

In the case of the per-site cache there are some headers added: Last-Modified, Cache-Control, etc.
See [Django per-site cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs#the-per-site-cache).

I was wondering if Django also adds them for the per-view cache. If not, is there a straightforward way to tell Django to add them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it just applies UpdateCacheMiddleware and FetchFromCacheMiddleware to a specific view.